# JavaScript Quicksort recursive

Tags: javascript, quicksort

I´m trying to implement a quicksort algorithm for an int array in JavaScript.
I´ve got a problem in my code. The first few ints get sorted well but at the end of the sortet array there is always one integer which is placed many times although its only one time in the array which should be sorted. Hopefully someone will find my fault.
Thanks.

```
function quicksort(array) {
    var randomPlace = Math.round(Math.random() * array.length);
    var pivotelement = array[randomPlace];
    left = new Array;
    right = new Array;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] < pivot) {
            left[left.length] = array[i];
        } else {
            right[right.length] = array[i];
        }
    }
    if ((left.length == 0 || left.length == 1) && (right.length == 0 || right.length == 1)) {
        return left.concat(right);
    } else if (left.length == 0 || left.length == 1) {
        return (left.concat((quicksort(right))));
    } else if (right.length == 0 || right.length == 1) {
        return ((quicksort(left)).concat(right));
    } else {
        return (quicksort(left)).concat((quicksort(right)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript quicksort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185864/javascript-quicksort)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are identifying the `randomPlace` wrongly. It returns `undefined` some times because you're using `Math.round()`.

Try this instead:

```
var randomPlace = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
```

Also, use the following code when initializing `left`, and `right`:

```
var left = new Array();
var right = new Array();
```

Also, you need to change the `pivot` in `array[i] < pivot` to `pivotElement`.

You can see my complete fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/md0bjzjq)

Answer (score 0):

Beside some nameming confusion, like `pivotelement` vs `pivot` and `Math.round` vs `Math.floor`, you need to tackle the problem of for example `[1, 1, 1]` which is always returning `left = []` and `right = [1, 1, 1]`, that calls `quicksort([1, 1, 1])` ad infinitum.

To overcome this problem, you need to check for empty `left` and with `right` every element, if it is equal to the random pivot. Then return `right`, without calling `quicksort` again.

```js
function quicksort(array) {
    var randomPlace = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length),
        pivot = array[randomPlace],
        left = [],
        right = [],
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        (array[i] < pivot ? left : right).push(array[i]);
    }
    console.log(pivot, JSON.stringify(array), JSON.stringify(left), JSON.stringify(right));

    // prevent looping forever
    if (!left.length && right.every(function (v) { return v === pivot; })) {
        return right;
    }

    if (left.length <= 1 && right.length <= 1) {
        return left.concat(right);
    }
    if (left.length <= 1) {
        return left.concat(quicksort(right));
    }
    if (right.length <= 1) {
        return quicksort(left).concat(right);
    }
    return quicksort(left).concat(quicksort(right));
}

console.log(quicksort([2, 7, 4, 8, 3, 11, 49, 20, 10, 1, 1, 1]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Another solution would be to separate the array into three arrays, one for smaller values, one for equal values and one for greater values. Then sort only the smaller and greater arrays.

```js
function quicksort(array) {
    var randomPlace = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length),
        pivotValue = array[randomPlace],
        left = [],
        pivot = [],
        right = [],
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === pivotValue) {
            pivot.push(array[i]);
            continue;
        }
        (array[i] < pivotValue ? left : right).push(array[i]);
    }

    console.log(pivotValue, JSON.stringify(array), JSON.stringify(left), JSON.stringify(pivot), JSON.stringify(right));

    if (left.length <= 1 && right.length <= 1) {
        return left.concat(pivot, right);
    }
    if (left.length <= 1) {
        return left.concat(pivot, quicksort(right));
    }
    if (right.length <= 1) {
        return quicksort(left).concat(pivot, right);
    }
    return quicksort(left).concat(pivot, quicksort(right));
}

console.log(quicksort([2, 7, 4, 8, 3, 11, 49, 20, 10, 1, 1, 1]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

heres a short version of quick sort written in JS exactly as it is seen in [Intro To Algorithms](https://mcdtu.files.wordpress.com/2017/03/introduction-to-algorithms-3rd-edition-sep-2010.pdf), hope this helps!

```
var partition = function (arr, low, high) {
    var x = arr[high]
    var i = low - 1
    for (var j = low; j <= high - 1; j++) {
        if (arr[j] <= x) {
            i++
            var temp = arr[i]
            arr[i] = arr[j]
            arr[j] = temp
        }
    }
    var temp = arr[i + 1]
    arr[i + 1] = arr[high]
    arr[high] = temp
    return i + 1 
}

var quickSort = function (arr, low, high) {
    if (low < high) {
        index = partition(arr,low,high)
        if (low < index-1) quickSort(arr,low,index-1)
        if (index+1 < high) quickSort(arr,index+1,high)
    }
}

var list2 = [1000,13,12,1001,82,1,2,4,3,0]

console.log(quickSort(list2,0,list2.length))
```

also on my [GitHub](https://github.com/dm20/Node-Structures/blob/master/Lists/generic%20helpers/quicksort.js)